# Connection changes at RUN TIME in JAVA app

Tags: java, jsp, jdbc, connection, connection-pooling

I have to create a JSP in which there is a screen which makes DB connection at 
runtime, means i have to provide DB details (thin client / driver info etc) at run time and then connect and procced with next pages and this is a small scale appln (Max 20 users) so I want 2 know how can i manage connections.

-- Store connections in Session ?
-- In HashTable with key as session id and value as connection ?
-- or some connection pool at run time (i dont think it is good)..
-- or create property file and make changes at runtime and reload it..

Let me know the best approach for this wrt performance and design.

Regards,
Amit

Answer (score 4):

you can set connection information(db Name,password,server Address,etc...) in .properties file. LIKE below.

1)static way
**config.properties**(generally it created at classPath-src\config.properties) file contains

```
driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
database=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbName
dbuser=root
dbpassword=root
```

you can also create or reset value

or **1)create or set dynamic properties file.**

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        Properties prop = new Properties();

        try {
            //set the properties value
            prop.setProperty("database", "localhost");
            prop.setProperty("dbuser", "patel");
            prop.setProperty("dbpassword", "password");

            //save properties to project root folder
            prop.store(new FileOutputStream("config.properties"), null);

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

output in (config.properties)

```
 dbpassword=password
 database=localhost
 dbuser=patel
```

**2)now time to read it at runtime.**

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        Properties prop = new Properties();

        try {
               //load a properties file
            prop.load(new FileInputStream("config.properties"));

               //get the property value and print it out
                System.out.println(prop.getProperty("database"));
            System.out.println(prop.getProperty("dbuser"));
            System.out.println(prop.getProperty("dbpassword"));

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

output

```
localhost
patel
password
```

pls write this code in jsp in  <% %>
this way u can load any thing at run time.
need any help ping me..................:)

Comment: But this jsp page will be accessed by serveral users and is it a good approch to change prpoerty file each time and modify it for example i am using db D1 some other D2 and some other D6 and so on and on next day D4,D9 and D10 so in that case i guess connection pool will not work as good approach..

Comment: you can create file for each user than create file by it's id
eg id=1 in session
file name will db1.properties or like that..........

Comment: creating file for each user is not a good approach, if 20 users connected then i have to create 20 files. :(

Comment: I was assuming that connection information is only available from the user over web.

Comment: Hi @PratikPatel. I see you deleted your question about PHP encryption, even though I'd taken the time to add several useful links to help you start your research. On StackOverflow you shouldn't worry about the odd down-vote or question close - it happens. Hopefully you now have a clearer idea of how to formulate questions. This is good too: http://whathaveyoutried.com/.

Answer (score 0):

You can use connection pooling

[check this](http://www.snaq.net/java/DBPool/)

Answer (score 0):

It may be simpler to store login credentials in the server memory map that uses session id as a key, reopen the connection on each call and close it at the end of servicing the call. While there is a penalty to open a connection, one per web interaction should be efficient enough. This guards against connection leak.

To prevent forged sessions ids that would be a security problem, your web server must make sure that the user is authenticated for each call.

Comment: I guess for each request i have to create new connection, serve using it and then close the connection in finally block. No connection pooling and no singletion isnt;d ?

Comment: Yes. The time to open the connection to the database that is in some next-standing machine should very small in comparison to the web request travel time to and then from your server. But your head will be free from connection leak troubles and also from thread safety troubles.